# ember need multiple markers on google map that are draggable

Tags: ember.js

I have a google map in my Ember app where I need to put some multiple markers on (dynamically generated).

Now I tried 2 addons:
1. ember-cli-g-maps: doesn't let me add multiple markers dynamically
2. ember-g-map: doesn't let me make the markers draggable

Am I doing something wrong and is it in fact possible with these addons? Or is there another way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 1. ember-cli-g-maps: doesn't let me add multiple markers dynamically

You can add markers dynamically, checkout: https://github.com/Matt-Jensen/ember-cli-g-maps/blob/master/tests/dummy/app/pods/basic-usage/markers/route.js